# Break down "il ne saurait s'agir d'une coincidence"

Tags: expressions

I'm guessing this means something like "il ne peut pas une coincidence", but I don't understand how you get that from "il ne saurait s'agir de.."

Comment: Note: that use of saurait is stylistic in French. It is not a conditional. It is a present tense in translation. The ne is called the ne explétif. Here, it is a negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an acception of *savoir* that is closely linked to *pouvoir*. It is marked as *literary* in the [TLFi, Level II/D](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/savoir), where is also mentioned that it is used with *ne* alone (that is, without *pas*: it actually is one of the last stronghold of this disappearing negating particle of the French language, though this specific expression is not the most commonly heard either).

> D. − [Croisements sém. avec pouvoir1]
>   1. Littér.  [Au cond. et au plus-que-parfait du subj. avec ne seul] Ne pas avoir le droit, la permission, la possibilité intérieure de (faire quelque chose, poser tel acte). [...] *On ne saurait dire; on ne saurait en conclure, en déduire (qqc., que), en dire autant de; on n'en saurait douter; on ne saurait trop rappeler, insister sur, recommander (qqc.).*
>   [...]
>   ♦ [Pour exprimer la probabilité] *Je vais vous montrer mon oncle Edward Sharper. Je l'ai laissé ici. Où diable s'est-il sauvé? Il ne saurait être bien loin!* (About, Roi mont., 1857, p. 294).
>   *– Source: TLFi*

So, « Il ne saurait s'agir d'une coincidence » could be rephrased:

- « Il ne peut [pas¹] s'agir d'une coincidence » or
- « Cela ne peut [pas¹] être une coincidence ».

From which we can conclude that the coincidence option has been ruled out: it is not a coincidence, at least according to the person who made the statement.

¹ **pas** may be used or left out in these cases, whereas it had to be left out in the original sentence.

Comment: Je crois qu'il s'agit de ce qu'on appelle _ne explétif_, non?

Comment: @user26328 Non, ici le "ne" a un vrai sens de négation. Le *ne explétif* n'apporte aucune négation.